# Editable field in view to display editable form only

Tags: views

I'm using the [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) module to create a view in which the user can edit the values of numerous fields.

Currently picking an editable table formatter and adding an editable field results in showing the current value of the field above and an editable form below it.

I would like to show only the form with the current value editable, is it possible?

If its possible with another module, please feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was informed lately that another module fits better my requirements so instead of [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews), I had to use [editablefields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) module.

Editable Fields provides you with an editable formatter which allows you to display the field as an editable form only.

Unfortunately it appears to be only on alpha2 for Drupal 7, but seems ok for my expectations.

Comment: Was gonna suggest it. Great module.